# unable to find the element in my application using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML code for element is:

```
<select id="pt1:reg2:1:soc1::content" class="x2h" title="" theme="dark" name="pt1:reg2:1:soc1">
```

Every time the xpath is getting changed but i am unable to find element.

```
WebElement w1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[starts-with(@id, 'pt1') AND contains(@id, ':soc1::content')]"));
Select s = new Select(w1);
s.selectByVisibleText("Commercial");
```

Comment: Use the brackets icon above the editor to separate code from text.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the xpath with a online tool like: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath
This query worked just fine, i changed the and to lowercase.

```
 .//select[starts-with(@id, 'pt1') and contains(@id, ':soc1::content')]
```

Comment: If my answer did  answer your question I would appropriate if you checked the answer. This will help people in the future to quickly find the correct answer. For more information on answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0):

Write Xpath in Double quotes "xpath here"  and 
Don't take first full stop '.' from xpath,its of no use.
It start with //

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
".//select[starts-with(@id, 'pt1') AND contains(@id, ':soc1::content')]"
```

Here full stop(.) before // need to be removed in Xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Below one is without "AND" which is also working fine.

```
//select[starts-with(@id, 'pt1')][contains(@id,':soc1::content')]
```